# Server in node which accepts cors from third party api, and then fetch it client side javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

I want to create node server that allows CORS, which accepts third party api JSON, and then fetch it in client side javascript.
So my question is how to set up server?
And then how to fetch data from that server ?

Third party api is https://api.kursna-lista.info/b7b80a59415046c33449b6a2a96bd4d8/kursna_lista

My node server is created like this.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('https://api.kursna-lista.info/b7b80a59415046c33449b6a2a96bd4d8/kursna_lista', function (req, res) {
  var data = res.data;

  res.json(data);
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

And then later fetch that api trough server in client side JavaScript.

```
fetch('name of the link from node sever').then(function(res) {
return res
}).then(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your problem is? be specific, "I want to" is not a question.

Comment: @Adriani6 edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic server in node to get started, you should install the 'request' package along with express for it to work. Request module will help make calls to the external api.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/api/get', function(req, res){
  request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: 'https://api.kursna-lista.info/b7b80a59415046c33449b6a2a96bd4d8/kursna_lista'
    }, function (error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        res.json(body);
      }
   })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now, to request that data from your server...

```
fetch('/api/get').then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't answered my question. What does 'api/get' means ?

Comment: This does in fact. "How to set up server and fetch the data" which my code does for you. "api/get" is the path to retrieve the data from the server. Yoi can set it to anything you wish, but your client side code must state the same path.

Comment: the naming is pretty vague, but that's a route. If I call $.get('http://www.yourdomain.com/api/get'...) from the client side, I should receive that kursna-lista data you included above. Weird, comment eats the http through www.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't understand Node or your question doesn't reflect what you expect.

Comment: @Adriani6, yes I am new at node. But i still don't get data from api when i run the server and fetch  the data, from you client side code. Thanks so much.

Comment: It should be localhost:3000/api/get